# spring boot + spring security + angularjs, custom login page not being displayed (404 error)

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot application with spring security and Angularjs as frontend.
when I deploy the application in weblogic server, it should open a custom login page (login.html) configured in the angularjs routes with the url '/login',  the url given in security file for login is loginPage("/login").

but its shows a 404 error, the url formed is http://localhost:7001/demo/login which is correct.

below is the security configuration

```
     http
     .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")

           .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
           .failureHandler(new MyAuthenticationFailureHandler())
           .usernameParameter("username")
           .passwordParameter("password")
           .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
            .logoutUrl("/logout")

            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
        .and()
        .addFilterAfter(new CSRFFilterBean(), CsrfFilter.class);
```

Below is the angularjs route configuration

```
$stateProvider
        .state("login",{
            url:'/login',
            templateUrl:'http://localhost:7001/demo/login.html', --- custom login form
            controller:'http://localhost:7001/demo/src/ContactLogin/controllers/ContactLoginCtrl.js'
        })
```

also added the entry for the inclusion of resource/template folder into the classpath

```
private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/templates/",
        "classpath:/static/","classpath:/static/js/","classpath:/static/js/lib/", "classpath:/public/", 
        "classpath:/static/js/src/"

}
```

Below is the screenshot of the location of the static files under src/main/resources
[image]

If I remove the complete security configuration shown above from the application, I am able to access the file with the url http://localhost:7001/demo/login.html otherwise
the url http://localhost:7001/demo/login is displayed with 404 error

please some body help me with this ..?

with the loginpage("/login") configured in spring security file, it redirects to the url http://localhost:7001/demo/login, now based on the url route configured in the baseApp it should display the login.html. In my case its giving 404 error
please some body help me .....

Comment: Can you share the complete code of your security configuration?

Comment: please suggest me any way to upload the zipped file of the project

Comment: @Moshe Arad thank u , uploaded the project at the link [ https://github.com/ksvasu4u/spring-boot ] could u please check it